# Ruby on Rails as portable app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, portability

Is there any way to run a RoR app as a 'portbale app'?

For instance, can you put an app including the ruby on rails stack, web server et all, on a stick and then just run it on a windows machine? Without installing?

There was project called Instant Rails that provided this more or less, but it's not maintained. (http://rubyforge.org/projects/instantrails/)

Also, there is RubyStack from Bitnami (http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack#nativeInstaller) but it needs to be installed (I can go with that, but rather not).

So, the question is, can Ruby on Rails, including a specific app, be made to run on any computer (well, let's start with Win) from a stick, CD or DVD, without having to install anything first?

Comment: probably you should check JRuby for this. Haven't used it myself, so can't help you any further, but with it you should be able to run rails in a JVM, wich should be portable.

Comment: another option might be rvm on cygwin - http://www.tiplite.com/how-to-install-rvm-on-windows-using-cygwin/ rvm installs everything in ~/.rvm, maybe this can be tweaked.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to install a development environment? Or do you mean you want to distribute a self-contained application to other users?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/distributingrubyapplications/rails.html

This tutorial walks you thru the entire process of creating a self-containing windows app that  bundles your rails application inside it.